# Leining Megillat Esther with Voices

Tags: torah-reading, megillat-esther

I know someone who, when leining Megillat Esther, they use a different voice for each character, and while their leining they speak in a tone of voice which represents how they believe the character would speak at this point of the story. He does a great job bringing the Megillah to life. My question is is there any halachig problem with doing thee voices?

Comment: You could reasonably do the same for Megillat Rut, or even much of the Torah.

Comment: I've always wanted to do a grumpy voice for קרבה שנת השבע שנת השמטה.  I never worked up the courage to do it though.

Comment: What, like falsetto for Esther's voice? Sounds a bit silly.

Comment: But is it halachigly allowed?

Comment: I'm unaware that changing one's voice while reading any part of Tanach in public poses any halachic problem unless it is done in a mocking way or diminishes from the focus of the reading, itself. (E.g. if one is intentionally changing the voice with the intention to be comedic, that may be a halachic problem.) Can you clarify why you think there may be a problem, otherwise? If anything, I think it may add to the meaning of what's going on, if it's done properly.